# Modify source file used for the Copy on the target machine

Tags: ansible

I'm using the Copy module to transfer a 10G file from my machine to the remote `/tmp` dir. However, Copy uses an intermediate folder inside `home` and I need to transfer the file **directly** to `/tmp` because `/home` doesn't have enough space.

Is it possible to control the `src` path used by the Copy module?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ansible.cfg change the "remote_tmp" to a location where sufficient space available or you run your playbook as below:

`ANSIBLE_REMOTE_TEMP=/dir1/some_dir/large_space/ ansible-playbook copy.yml`

[Official Documentation for ANSIBLE_REMOTE_TEMP with shell plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/shell/sh.html?highlight=ansible_remote_temp)